# How to set up a notification on S3 after reaching a number of objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to set an alert on the S3 bucket which is invoked when certain number of files are put into the bucket?

For example, an alert is generated when there are more than 7 objects in a bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 has a [Cloudwatch metric for the number of objects in a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/s3-metricscollected.html#s3-cloudwatch-metrics) so you could use that with a [Cloudwatch alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#CloudWatchAlarms).